# Java logger и несколько filehandler

Tags: java, логирование

Есть один статический logger и 4 различных файла куда пишется информация в зависимости от условия работы приложения.
Сущесвует ли способ в стандартном `java.util.logging` выбирать конкретный `FileHandler` и остальные не использовать?
Способ:

```
LOGGER.removeHandler(user file);
LOGGER.addHandler(system file);
LOGGER.INFO(ЧТО ТО НЕ ТАК В СИСТЕМЕ);
```

Не нравится своей конструкцией `switch`